# A better way to use filters/objects in Angular controllers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm setting a rootScope variable to maintain the state of the program.  This works, but I don't think it's quite 'right'.  Is there a better way to select an object from an array?

Here's my current code.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('packingCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$rootScope', function($scope, $http, $filter, $rootScope) {
    $http.get('data/trayData.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.trays = data;
    });
    var currentOrder = $rootScope.currentlyPacking;;
    $http.get('data/orderData.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.orders = data;
        $scope.current = $filter('filter')($scope.orders, {orderId: currentOrder});
    });
}])
```

Thanks in advance for any insight / best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service to hold your state. Each service instance is a singleton, so when the service is injected into various controllers, all will see the same state.

```
var currentlyPackingSvc = function($http) {
    var currentlyPacking = {

    }

    return {
        currentlyPacking: currentlyPacking,
        getTrays: function() { /* make $http call and update currentlyPacking */ },
        getOrders: function() { /* make $http call and update currentlyPacking */  }
    }
}

angular.service('currentlyPackingSvc', ['$http', currentlyPackingSvc]);

angular.controller('packingCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$rootScope', 'currentlyPackingSvc'
                     function($scope, $http, $filter, $rootScope, currentlyPackingSvc) {
    ...
    var currentOrder = currentlyPackingSvc.currentlyPacking;
    ...
}]);
```

Assuming you leave your 'currentlyPacking' property as an object, the changes should automatically be pushed to your scope.

This way, you have all your state isolated to one service that can be utilized anywhere.